# Calcular el coeficiente de Gini

Tags: array, r, matemáticas

Quiero calcular el coeficiente de Gini en un conjunto de datos de rendimiento de precio de las acciones gracias a la fórmula siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde **X** es la parte acumulativa de la población, e **Y** es la parte acumulada de los ingresos.

Tengo **Y**, las devoluciones. No sé si necesitan ser ordenar :

```
> cumulative_income
      .SXQR       .SXTR       .SXNR       .SXMR       .SXAR       .SX3R       .SX6R       .SXFR 
-0.09683670 -0.09093681 -0.35780722 -0.63732702 -0.70266238 -0.41770434 -0.35208188 -0.26594526 
      .SXOR       .SXDR       .SX4R       .SXRR       .SXER       .SXKR       .SX7R       .SX8R 
-0.34401190 -0.14020891 -0.10369136 -0.32921795 -0.17200268 -0.86653081 -0.72620602 -1.31523823 
      .SXIR       .SXPR 
-1.30391823 -1.36977663
```

Y **W**, los pesos individuales.

```
> w
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,] 0.04591712 0.04078667 0.04126135 0.05131896 0.04349168 0.04834431 0.04694083 0.03904389
           [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]      [,14]     [,15]      [,16]
[1,] 0.04117694 0.04537461 0.04692524 0.04045692 0.04696848 0.05087293 0.1713231 0.08499888
          [,17]     [,18]
[1,] 0.04396601 0.0708321
```

Entonces cómo puedo calcular este formula ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que el coeficiente Gini se obtiene en función de las areas de un **Triangulo Isósceles** y **la Curva de Lorenz**, siempre dicho coeficiente será positivo, por otro lado, como **R** a diferencia de **Python**, no indexa los arreglos desde cero (`0`), sugiero trabajar con la siguiente expresión tomada de [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_de_Gini):

[image: GiniFormula]

Entonces teniéndose los siguientes datos:

```
W=c( 0.04591712, 0.04078667, 0.04126135, 
     0.05131896, 0.04349168, 0.04834431, 
     0.04694083, 0.03904389, 0.04117694,
     0.04537461, 0.04692524, 0.04045692,
     0.04696848, 0.05087293, 0.1713231, 
     0.08499888, 0.04396601, 0.0708321)


Income=c(
    -0.09683670, -0.09093681, -0.35780722,
    -0.63732702, -0.70266238, -0.41770434,
    -0.35208188, -0.26594526, -0.34401190,
    -0.14020891, -0.10369136, -0.32921795,
    -0.17200268, -0.86653081, -0.72620602,
    -1.31523823, -1.30391823, -1.36977663 )
```

Como la sumatoria va desde `1` hasta `n-1`, se puede agregar un cero (`0`) al inicio de los vectores `Income` y `W` a fin de allanar los cálculos en **R**.

```
n <- length(Income) # Es 18, "W" también debe tener la misma longitud
```

Las `Xs y Ys` mayúsculas representan las frecuencias acumuladas de `W` e `Income`respectivamente, por tanto, primero hay que obtener las frecuencias relativas de dichos valores:

```
dy <- c(0,Income)/sum(Income) # Frecuencia Relativa Income
dx <- c(0,W)/sum(W)           # Frecuencia Relativa wW
```

Luego se procede a obtener las Frecuencias Acumuladas

```
Sy <- cumsum(dy)
Sx <- cumsum(dx)
```

Después se hace necesario vectorizar las operaciones que van dentro de la Fórmula sumatoria para las `Xs y Ys`:

```
Xx <- Sx[2:(n+1)] - Sx[1:n] # Posición k+1 - Posición k
Yy <- Sy[2:(n+1)] + Sy[1:n] # Posición k+1 + Posición k
```

Entonces el coeficiente de Gini sería:

```
Gini<-abs(1 - sum(Xx*Yy))
Gini
[1] 0.1963448
```

Luego si se desea, se puede realizar el gráfico respectivo, para ello es necesario agregar una Línea de Equidad de 45 grados:

```
# linea de equidad 45 grados
EqVect<-cumsum((0:n)/sum(1:n))
EqVect

plot(Sx,Sy, type="l", col="red",ylab="Income",xlab="W")
lines(EqVect,EqVect, type="l", lty=2, col="blue")
legend("topleft",col = c("Red","Blue"), lty=c(1,2), lwd=c(1,1),  cex=0.75, c("Curva De Lorenz Acciones", "Linea de Equidad"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** He trabajado con la notación `delta` de `x` e `y` (`dx`,`dy`) a pesar de hablar de frecuencias relativas porque los cálculos en sí mismo, representan relaciones entre áreas.